# firebase could not parse the android application module's gradle config

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I have tried everything I even remove the jcenter line. I really do not know what is wrong with my gradle files this error did not show on my last projects, Please help I have a deadline and I cant get past this error.

#### My Gradle file's Screenshot

[image: Gradle]

Answer (score 1):

Where is this line?:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'  // Google Services plugin
```

[See documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).